# сравнение значений одной и тойже переменной в двух инстансах одного и того же метода(Corutine)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть некий метод инициализирующий старт корутины вида:

```
public void Initialize(float variable){
    var newestcorutine = StartCoroutine(MyCorutine(variable));
}
```

И таких инстансов может быть неопределённо много.
Цель сравнить значения variable (например найти большую) срез всех действующих в данный момент инстансов.

Как это вообще можно сделать если это можно сделать (мне кажется что можно но я даже не представляю с чего начать чтобы сравнивать переменную саму с собой)?

Сама корутина имеет примерный вид типа :

```
private IEnumerator MyCorutine(float variable1, int variable2) 
{
    var durationTimerS = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var durationTimerA = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    while (durationTimerS.Elapsed.TotalSeconds <= variable1)
    {
        var timeLeft = variable1 - durationTimerS.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        BindedText.text = timeLeft.ToString("0");

        if (variableBool == false)
        {                
            durationTimerS.Stop();                
            durationTimerS.Reset();
            durationTimerA.Stop();
            durationTimerA.Reset();
            yield break;
        }

        if (durationTimerS.Elapsed.TotalSeconds >= (duration / 3) * 2 &&
            durationTimerA.Elapsed.TotalSeconds >= 0.4f) 
        {               
            BindedImage().alpha = 0.3f;
        }
        if (durationTimerS.Elapsed.TotalSeconds >= (duration / 3) * 2 &&
            durationTimerA.Elapsed.TotalSeconds >= 0.8f)
        {
            BindedImage().alpha = 1f;
            durationTimerA.Reset();
            durationTimerA.Start();
        }

        SomeOtherScript.SomeOtherMethod(-variable2, variableBool);
        yield return null;
    }

    variableBool = false;
    BindedImage().alpha = 0;
    durationTimerS.Stop();
    durationTimerS.Reset();
    durationTimerA.Stop();
    durationTimerA.Reset();
}
```

Актуальная задача в некий момент времени найти все активные инстансы этой корутины и найти имеющую наибольшее значение переменной

На текущий момент я решаю эту задачу так
Есть глобальная переменная вида public Corutine newCorutine1
и к ней в пару глобальная переменная public int variableValue1

Cоотвественно инициализирую я так newCorutine1 = StartCorutine(MyCorutine(variable));
и присваиваю variableValue1 = variable;

Соотвественно второй инстанс запускается уже как
 newCorutine2 = StartCorutine(MyCorutine(variable));
и присваиваю variableValue2 = variable;

В самом теле корутины я по завершению инстанса я обнуляю variableValue 
Соответственно потом когда мне нужно найти инстанс с наибольшим\наименьшим значением я просто делаю перебор по списку variableValue
Подход вполне работает но не очень удобен и при росте числа инстансов будет совсем совсем не удобен.
Поэтому хотелось бы найти менее "в лоб" решение.

Comment: А работа в `MyCorutine` происходит бесконечно или сделало что-то и успокоилось?

Comment: Сделало и успокоилось но длительность активности зависит от переменных при инциализации.

Comment: А можете более подробно в вопросе это описать? Показать что там еще за коды есть. Что там в `MyCorutine` например. А то есть некое решение, но пока не уверен, подойдет ли оно..... Хотя сама задача несколько странная. Мне кажется это похоже на [проблему XY](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710/191482)

Comment: Посмотрите сюда https://habrahabr.ru/post/216185/, возможно поможет. `Соответственно потом когда мне нужно найти инстанс с наибольшим\наименьшим значением я просто делаю перебор по списку variableValue` ..... что-то подобное и можно делать... объявляете словарь, ключ-значение. где ключ - идентификатор корутины, значение - variable....и бегаете именно по словарю